# How can I bind event handlers in Telerik MVC ClientTemplates?

Tags: javascript, telerik-mvc

I'm trying to call a function with arguments from Telerik grid ClientTemplate, like this:

```
.ClientTemplate("<a href=\"javascript:OnModifyDescription('<#= Value1 #>');\" title='Modify'>...</a>")
```

When the `Value` argument contains a single quote then on clicking the link results in the error: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"`.

What is the correct way to bind a function in a ClientTemplate?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is everything on one line? And for the love of ... well, everyone, don't *ever* use `href="javascript:..."` links!

Comment: Thanks for reply. The code is wrapped now. Could you please advise me the correct syntax then?

Comment: This is not about syntax. Your entire approach is wrong, correcting the syntax will not lead you anywhere. Unfortunately I don't know enough about Telerik MVC to guide you. I've re-phrased your question a bit, though. Maybe someone else sees it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your client template as this :

```
.ClientTemplate("<a class='MyClass' myAttrib='<#= Value1 #>') title='Modify'>...</a>")
```

Then write the following scripts at top of your page:

```
<script>
$('a.MyClass').live('click',function(){
   var myVal = $(this).attr('myAttrib');
   OnModifyDescription(myVal);
});
</script>
```

Check this for `jquery live` function : http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @Alexander Note that `.live()` is deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and no longer exists in jQuery 1.9. Use `.on()` in new code.

Comment: @Mahmoud While this might work, it still feels wrong. The whole point of MVC libraries is that you don't have to do these things manually.

Comment: @Tolmak Telerik MVC Extentions are build based on JQuery 1.6 (as I remember).

Comment: @Tomalak why wrong? In all of your enterprise usages you will need JavaScript coding in different levels. Moreover, Telerik MVC Extensions is not the best one(Indeed it is deprecated and next generation is KendoUI). Currently I work with Sencha ExtJS which is more comprehensive than Telerik components but I need these coding too...It is really depends on your UI desing (more responsive, more complexity and more JS codes)

Comment: Well if that's the way it's done in Telerik MVC, there's nothing wrong with it. It just feels unclean to me. As I said in my comment to the question I don't really know a lot about it.

Comment: yes but you said: "The whole point of MVC libraries is that you don't have to do these things manually". Indeed in any MVC(or none mvc libraries) you may need to do lots of things manually. ExtJS, Kendo, DevExpress, ... all of them may help us alot but different simple or complex situations may force us to write these dummy or wise codes! :)